# Can't login using javascript through webview - android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want to use javascript to login to a news website so that I can view the full content of the news. I try some coding of my own after reading some post here but it doesn't work.

The website : http://m.malaysiakini.com/news/363188

Website form : [image]

**EDIT**: Changed my code to answer below but still doesn't work

My source code :

```
webViewLoadURL();
    webView.loadUrl("http://m.malaysiakini.com/news/363188");

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        String user = "username";
        String pass = "password";

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                    "$('input#username').val(" + user + ");" +
                    "$('input#password').val(" + pass + ");" +
                    "$('button.uk-button-primary').click();" +
                    "};");
        }

        public void onPageFinished2(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery seems to be already loaded on the page so you can use it to populate the two fields then click the submit button.

```
$('input#username').val("username");
$('input#username').val("password");
$('button.uk-button-primary').click();
```

just change val on the first line to the username you want to use inside quotes and the password in the second.

If you are using google chrome and just paste this code into the console, it should work (assuming you have the right loging creds).

Comment: Hello, I tried it in google chrome and it work but not in my code :\

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work? Did you get an error?  Or did it say you had the wrong credentials?

Comment: Your answer is right. But the actual reason why I can't log in is due to security issue originating from the website. I'll just accept it as an answer anyway.